# MongoDB - Find Data from a array inside a object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have my db in following form

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56fc92adcf908c9f296e5885"),
"_class" : "com.abc.ppm.dto.AccessAttemptDTO",
"url" : "/myProject/edit",
"ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
"param" : {
    "iecode" : [ 
        "P1234"
    ],
    "id" : [ 
        "5696578c6d34f835dc632fdd "
    ]
},
"accessTime" : "30-3-2016 10:59:57",
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",
"entity" : "admin",
"entityCode" : ""
},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("56fc92adcf908c9f296e5887"),
"_class" : "com.abc.ppm.dto.AccessAttemptDTO",
"url" : "/myProject/edit",
"ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
"param" : {
    "iecode" : [ 
        "P1122"
    ],
    "id" : [ 
        "5696578c6d34f835dc632fdd "
    ]
},
"accessTime" : "30-3-2016 10:59:57",
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",
"entity" : "admin",
"entityCode" : ""
```

}

Now I want to find all the enries where iecode is 'P1234'. How do I do that? (Note: iecodes value is stored in string array format.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write query like:

```
db.collectionName.find({"param.iecode": "P1234"})
```